# socket.on doesn't fire the first time

Tags: javascript, events, socket.io

Why doesn't this fire the first time? I'm not sure I understand this, please help! When I run pause() the second time, then it fires. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

```
    this.pause = function (stopwatch){
         this.stopwatch = stopwatch;

         socket.emit('pauseTime');  //server does fire "paustime"

         // this doesn't fire
         socket.on('pauseTimeClock', function(data){
            stopWatchClock.setPausedTime(data.time);
            $('.pauseTime').html(data.time.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span>$1</span>'))       
            console.log(stopWatchClock.pausedTime);       
        });


        this.stopwatch.changeState(this.stopwatch.getPauseState());
    }
```

server code

```
socket.on('pauseTime', function () {
//stop broadcasting countDown time
clearInterval(timeinterval);

var pausedTime = moment();

function pauseTimeClock() {

  var timeDiffHour = moment().hour() - pausedTime.hour();
  var timeDiffMinute = moment().minute() - pausedTime.minute();
  var timeDiffSec = moment().second();

  var displayTime = timeDiffHour + ":" + timeDiffMinute + ":" + timeDiffSec;

  socket.broadcast.emit("pauseTimeClock", { time: moment(displayTime, 'hhmm').format('HH:mm') });

  console.log(timeDiffHour);
  console.log(timeDiffMinute);
}

setInterval(pauseTimeClock, 1000);
```

})

Comment: you don't subscribe to 'pauseTimeClock' events until the pause method is called

Comment: You shouldn't put .on() inside a function as every time the function is called the listener is declared again and possible duplicated.

Comment: it doesn't fire the first time because your pauseTimeClock isn't defined when you get the response

Comment: declare the .on('pauseTimeClock') outside of the .pause function

Comment: thanks all ! that seem to fixed the problem. However, my jquery  $('.pauseTime').html(data.time.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span>$1</span>'))  doesn't fire until I refresh the page. Any idea why this is? thanks ahead!